# Laravel One to Many and Many to Many for the same Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-resource, laravel-models

I am trying to make a task management system. Users can create a task and assign multiple users to the task. So the task table will have a user_id for identifying the user who created the task. There is a pivot table that consists of user_id and task_id so that the assignees of the task can be mapped there.

tasks table details

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->Integer('views');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

users table structure

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

pivot table task_user structure

```
Schema::create('task_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('task_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('status')->default('TODO');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Task model has this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

User model has this

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
}
```

Now I have a Task Resource with data fetching from UserResource but I am only able to get the data from a pivot table.

```
return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'views' => $this->views,
        'user' => UserResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('users')),
        'comments' => CommentResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('comments')),
        'assingnees' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('users', function () {
            return $this->users->pluck('pivot.user_id')->unique()->all();
        }),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
```

I want the user details from the pivot table in `assignees` and the user details from the tasks table in `user`. But eventually, I ended up getting pivot table users in `user`, and no `assignees` variable is obtained in JSON response. How can I get both user data in separate variables?

Comment: Can you specify the source from the "Task Resource" function that is querying this data?

Comment: you have to add another `belongsTo` relation in the task table to get the user that created the task.

Comment: @McWayWeb .. sorry I didn't understand.. TaskResource source??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Where should I add? in the Task Model file?  It has this already..
`public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }`

Comment: this relationship returns users from pivot table..the user who created the task has the id in the task table..so you have to add another `belogsTo` ralation in Task Model.

Comment: Ok. So I am confused that what would be the function name for that?.. If i give users(), it will show error.

Comment: name anything like `createdBy` and pass the foreign key so laravel can understand which foreign key to use.

Comment: Yeah. Sure.. I will try it out.